# How to avoid prop drilling in Atomic design?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks

I recently got a new project. The project used Atomic design but the developer that worked on the project begore didn't follow the rule exactly. Molecules and organisms have a logic with API(axios). In the design, They have to do their features with props, right?

So I decided to seperate the logics that they're using. While working it, I got a curiosity. Components that made with the Atomic design are really clean. I know that but how about a prop drilling?

Pages pass props to organisms.
Organisms pass props to molecules and atoms.
Molecules pass propd to atoms.

Context API came out for solving this problem, but this isn't along with Atomic design.

Do I misunderdtand a concept of the design?

How do you guys avoid a prop drilling in Atomic design? Do I have to work with it?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same question I am having. seems this question disserve more attention.

Comment: Even I am looking same on this issue but specifically with angular, and I have understood this just pass function reference from Page/organisms to atoms and when actual event/interaction happen at atom level function will be called, but I am still unsure about complexity of complex/nested UI

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion I can give you is use Component composition.

#### Current architecture with lots of props drilling

```
// Smart Component
function Payments() {
  const {cards, setAsDefault, paymentHistory, viewPaymentDetails} = usePayment();
  return(
    <PaymentsList cards={cards} setAsDefault={setAsDefault} paymentHistory={paymentHistory} viewPaymentDetails={viewPaymentDetails}/>
  )
}
```

```
// Organism
function PaymentsList({cards, setAsDefault, paymentHistory, viewPaymentDetails}) {
  return(
    <>
      <h1>This is your payment page with history of transactions and saved cards<h1/>
      <SavedCards cards={cards} setAsDefault={setAsDefault}>
      <HistoryOfPayments paymentHistory={paymentHistory} viewPaymentDetails={viewPaymentDetails}/> // Listing similar to SavedCards
    </>
  )
}
```

```
// Molecule
function SavedCards({cards, setAsDefault}) {
  return(
    <ul>
      {cards.map((card) => (<CardItem setAsDefault={setAsDefault}/ >))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

```
// Atom
function CardItem({setAsDefault}) {
  return(<li onClick={setAsDefault}>Card 1</li>)
}
```

as you can see here, the component SavedCards received setAsDefault just to pass it to its child CardItem. SavedCards doesn't ever need this prop.

We can improve it with Component Composition:

#### With Composition

```
// Smart Component
function Payments() {
  const {cards, setAsDefault, paymentHistory, viewPaymentDetails} = usePayment();
  return(
    <PaymentsList>
      <SavedCards cards={cards}>
        <CardItem setAsDefault={setAsDefault} />
      <SavedCards/>
      <HistoryOfPayments>
        <AnyComponentHere></AnyComponentHere>
      </HistoryOfPayments>
    <PaymentsList/>
  )
}
```

```
// Organism
function PaymentsList({children}) {
  return(
    <>
      <h1>This is your payment page with history of transactions and saved cards<h1/>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

```
// Molecule
function SavedCards({children, cards}) {
  return(
    <ul>
      {cards.map((card) => children))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

```
// Atom
function CardItem({setAsDefault}) {
  return(<li onClick={setAsDefault}>Card 1</li>)
}
```

In summary, it looks like this:

```
<Organism>
    <Molecule>
        <Atom>{caption}</Atom>
    </Molecule>
</Organism>
```